# How to make copy of tables in Oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

I need to send a couple of tables from our Oracle database to one of our developers.
I usually just send the entire database. But how to send only selected tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Export tool from oracle.

```
exp scott/tiger file=emp.dmp tables=(emp,dept)
```

Here is a link to the [FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Import_Export_FAQ) from oracle.